# Bricscad V12 on ubuntu 11.10!

Tags: installation

i tried to install bricscad from the deb file but is for 32bit systems.So i had problems and i downloaded the .tgz file and ran tar -xvf and i was in the directory /opt/bricsys/bricscad/v12
So i managed to run bricscad with the command sudo sh bricscad.sh in the directory this.So my question is, do you have any idea of how to make a launcher or smthing so i can run the program from an easier way?I cannot find it in dash(unity) or in the desktop.

Any help will be great! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can create the launcher you need.
Fist of all, my Ubuntu is in Spanish, so I will translate some words; I hope you understand me.

**1.- Create a proper script that run the Bricscad script.**

Open *gedit* and write this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd <path_to_Bricscad_script>
sh .bricscad.sh
```

Save the file into your personal folder (**/home/your_user_name**) with the name **.run_cad.sh** (the fist dot hides the file, only if you want to hide it).

**2.- Create the launcher.**

For Unity: Press the *Super* key (that one it usually has the MS Windows logo) and write *Main Menu* (this is my translation from spanish). So, you will find a program to create launchers. Select a menu, for example *Graphics*, and then click on the *New Item* button. Select an *aplication* type, choose a name, an icon, a comment, and for the *command* option write **sh .run_cad.sh**.

**3.- Create a Unity launcher (optional).**

If you want an icon on the Unity launcher, look for your app using the dash, and then drag it and drop it over the Unity laucher.

Ariel

Comment: Thank you very much!Your help gave me a very nice information about scripting because i am learning about python now on!So, i want to ask you something more.I installed google sketchup with playonlinux.The launcher is ready automatically from playonlinux but when i double click that it does nothing. In the properties i found the command it uses-->/usr/share/playonlinux/playonlinux --run "Google SketchUp"

Comment: I am trying to learn Python too! About your problem... what happen if you run that command on a terminal? Nothing too?

Comment: well, when i  run it from terminal does nothing!It gives me the same error as i run playonlinux from terminal. Here is the message

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wrapper.py", line 25, in <module>
    import wx
ImportError: No module named wx

Comment: It seems that the program you execute needs a module called "wx", and you don´t have it. You can try with: **sudo apt-get install python-wxgtk2.8** and try again.

Comment: Here is someone who seems to have the same problem: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150423/installation-wxpython-on-ubuntu-11-10)

Comment: Please, if you have solved the post question, mark it as solved.

Comment: no,does not work!Same thing again!So?

Comment: Maybe you can create a new post with this problem. Remember I am just learning Python.

Answer (score 0):

In Kubuntu / KDE I can simply right click on the [K] (start) button and then choose "Edit applications". A small application window appears that lets you define new entries in the menu. I bet for Ubuntu there is a simalar way of adding launchers.